# How to pay to certain merchant from popup window paypal

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

I have a website in which a user posts invitations to events at a certain price. Others users will have to book this invitations. I want to integrate a paypal solution but I don't want to store any credit card information. I just that when a user wants tot book an event, a popul with paypal will appear, asking them to pay an ammount to a certain account, that I can set programatically for the receiver. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The users will have to signup to paypal's merchant services themselves. They will then receive a code snippet (which would normally be pasted into their own site). See this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

You could then create a form on your site that asks the user to enter their tokenID through a POST request that echos out onto their profile page or where ever. Check the merchant services settings yourself, you can customise the landing page for passing price parameters.

```
<iframe src="https://payflowlink.paypal.com?
MODE=TEST&SECURETOKENID=MySecureTokenID&SECURETOKEN=MySecureToken"
name="test_iframe" scrolling="no" width="570px" height="540px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Assuming you are storing the event info in a database, you would also store their paypal email address.  Then when you create the paypal pay button you would populate the business field with their email address.

`<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="business" VALUE="<?php echo $recipientEmail; ?>">`

As OBV said, they would have to have already created their paypal account.